# jQuery on click select first class and not all classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery function :

```
$(".clack").hide();
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(".clack").fadeThenSlideToggle();
});
```

Works great except all `clack` classes are toggled now.
Any idea how to open only the first class `.clack` after the clicked class `.click`?

I tried `.clack:first` but this results in only the first instance of class `.clack` being opened.
I want to open the first class `.clack` found after the clicked class `.click`.

I know I can rewrite my html and jQuery function with other solutions but the problem is the amount of data already existing for this function is very big.

My HTML :

```
 <img class="click" style="cursor: pointer;" src="someimg.jpg"/>
 <div class="clack">TEST TEXT1</div>
 <img class="click" style="cursor: pointer;" src="someimg2.jpg"/>
 <div class="clack">TEST TEXT2</div>
 <img class="click" style="cursor: pointer;" src="someimg3.jpg"/>
 <div class="clack">TEST TEXT3</div>
```

EXACT HTML EXAMPLE :

```
 <strong>
   <span>
     <img class="aligncenter click" src="img1.jpg" alt="vesteging" width="436" height="36" />
   </span>
 </strong>
</p>
<div class="clack">
  <center>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt;">DATA TEXT 1</span>
  </center>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: jQuery has a section of documentation on [DOM traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing). Probably a good idea to study it.

Answer (score 2):

You can target only the `.clack` that comes immediately after the clicked `.click`

```
$('.click').click(function(){
  $(this).next(".clack").fadeThenSlideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried this because there are a lot of these examples found on the internet like this but does not work. Code is fine, no errors but nothing happens when clicked.

Comment: @user3794845 then you did not show us your actual DOM because this should work.

Comment: If your HTML structure is as posted, then the above will surely target the immediately next `.clack` element. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: This looks like your answer right here user3794845.

Comment: @user3794845: You included the plugin that adds `fadeThenSlideToggle` right?

Comment: Yes, thanks included the plugin and works perfect but only for all classes.

Comment: @user3794845: That HTML example is unreadable. The solution works with the HTML you posted in your question. If it doesn't for you, I encourage you to go to http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and try some things on your own.

Comment: `$(this).closest('p,h3').next('.clack')`

Comment: Karl, many thanks for taking the time to read the source.
Your functions works perfect.. ! Can you explain short ?

Comment: @user3794845: Wow, your HTML structure looks nothing like what you had posted in the question. Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to the world of wordpress and user input trough wysiwyg.